# Adding scroll bars to a div that does not have a set height

Tags: html, css

I have been having a problem with a little project I have been working on. I have a header and a footer and middle content. I want to have the middle content have a scrolling feature but I cannot set a definitive height. Is there a way to get around the required height for scroll to work?

```css
#Bar, #sea {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}
  
#header {
 font-size: 50px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 25px;
}

#form {
  text-align: center;
}

#Bar {
  height: 35px;
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #c7c7cd;
}

#Bar:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #3A89D8;
}

#sea:active { 
 outline: none;
 border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #3A89D8; 
    background-color: #1172d2;
}

#sea:focus { 
 outline: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #3A89D8;
}

#sea {
  background-color: #4199F0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  height: 35px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-color: #3A89D8;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
}

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Arial;
}

#hid {
 visibility: hidden;
}

#NoteHolder {
 padding-left: 125px;
 padding-right: 125px;
 overflow: auto;
}

#BarHold {
 padding-top: 10px;
}

#SearchOP {
 top: 0; 
 left: 0; 
 position: fixed; 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 120%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
 display: none;
}

#NavSave {
 top: 0; 
 left: 0; 
 position: fixed; 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 120%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
 display: none;
}

#popupBoxOnePosition {
 top: 0; 
 left: 0; 
 position: fixed; 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 120%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
 display: none;
}

.popupBoxWrapper {
 width: 550px;
 margin: 50px auto; 
 text-align: left;
}

.popupBoxContent {
 background-color: #FFF; 
 padding: 15px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#popup-Sub {
 -moz-border-radius: 0px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
   border-radius: 0px;
   height: 45px;
   background-color: #3232ff;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 15px;
   float: right;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   border-color: #1919ff;
   text-align: center;
   width: 80px;
   font-weight: bold;
}

.HeaderNote {
 color: #7E7E7E;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 12px;
}

#Col {
 font-weight: bold;
}

table {
 border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: auto;
}

th, td {
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}

th {
 background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

#Oper {
 float: right;
 padding-right: 15px;
 cursor: default;
}

a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#NoteAv {
 top: 0; 
 left: 0; 
 position: fixed; 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 120%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
 display: none;
}

#Settings {
 top: 0; 
 left: 0; 
 position: fixed; 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 120%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
 display: none;
}

#FirstVisit {
 top: 0; 
 left: 0; 
 position: fixed; 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 120%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
 display: none;
}


#MarkList {
 vertical-align: middle;
 position: fixed;
    display: inline;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 56px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #3A89D8;
    background-color: #eff5f9;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#MarkList > button {
 height: 36px;
 color: #39739d;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #E1ECF4;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #39739d;
}


.YelColBox {
 background-color: #F0F041;
}

.LastCol {
 background-color: #F0F041;
}

.GreColBox {
 background-color: #62ff62;
}

.BluColBox {
 background-color: #4199F0;
}

.PurColBox {
 background-color: #9941F0;
}

.RedColBox {
 background-color: #F04141;
}

.OraColBox {
 background-color: #F09941;
}

.ColorBox {   
 float: right;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

```html
<body onload="FirstVisit('Settings');">
  <div style="height: 30%;">
    <div>
      <a id="Oper" onClick="toggle_visibility('NoteAv');">Notes</a><a id="Oper" onClick="toggle_visibility('Settings');">Settings</a>
      <p id="header">Note Searcher</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <p id="form">
      <input onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length)" class="SearchInp" autocomplete="off" id="Bar" name="Input" type="text" placeholder="Removed JS for the fiddle.">
      <input class="SearchInp" type="submit" id="sea" onClick="SetOff ()" value="Search">
      <br>
      <input id="Highlight" type="radio" name="textOp" checked>Highlight
      <input id="Filter" type="radio" name="textOp">Filter
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="NoteHolder">
    <p class="NoteOp">
    Imagine if this filled up the whole text area. 
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id=Hid>

  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="note.js"></script>
  <footer id="MarkList">
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Setting `overflow:scroll` on almost any element will add scrollbars, but they will be disabled, since the container will most likely increase in size to hold its contents.

Comment: How do you enable them? I set the middle dig to overflow scroll.

Comment: Well, I can't really say much, since you haven't shown any code...

Comment: I'll get the code. I'll try to put it on Jsfiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v6mhf83u/ JS was removed it is used to highlight notes. The button footer stores my searches and the middle is what I want to have a scroll bar.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a Stack Snippet so it's easier to see what's going on without leaving SO. Feel free to [edit] and remove if you don't like.

Comment: Unrelated: please try to minimize the code for describing your problem.

Comment: @xiaoyi I did not add the code.

Comment: @Hawkeye the shorter your code snippet is the more likely some one will answer your question. For starters, the css for background stuff is definitely unrelated to the problem.

Comment: @xiaoyi I am trying to remove it and add a link to the fiddle but it keeps telling me the link needs to be accompanied by code?

Comment: @Hawkeye a link to fiddle is not favorable, as one won't be able to see the problem directly. Please refer to the question guidelines and modify your problem description.

Comment: How will I display my issue then? @MikeMcCaughan wanted the code and I gave the code.

Comment: I edited the code from the jsfiddle link into the question. @xiaoyi is talking about reducing the amount of code involved to enable the ability to see the problem more clearly. See [mcve].

Comment: Please do not go around the rules around jsfiddle links and include the code. I've rolled back your edit which removed the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `overflow` property to `scroll` will show scrollbars (albeit disabled).

```css
#Bar, #sea {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}
  
#header {
 font-size: 50px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 25px;
}

#form {
  text-align: center;
}

#Bar {
  height: 35px;
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  vertical-align: top;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #c7c7cd;
}

#Bar:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #3A89D8;
}

#sea:active { 
 outline: none;
 border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #3A89D8; 
    background-color: #1172d2;
}

#sea:focus { 
 outline: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #3A89D8;
}

#sea {
  background-color: #4199F0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  height: 35px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-color: #3A89D8;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: top;
}

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Arial;
}

#hid {
 visibility: hidden;
}

#NoteHolder {
 padding-left: 125px;
 padding-right: 125px;
 overflow: scroll;
}

#BarHold {
 padding-top: 10px;
}

#SearchOP {
 top: 0; 
 left: 0; 
 position: fixed; 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 120%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
 display: none;
}

#NavSave {
 top: 0; 
 left: 0; 
 position: fixed; 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 120%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
 display: none;
}

#popupBoxOnePosition {
 top: 0; 
 left: 0; 
 position: fixed; 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 120%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
 display: none;
}

.popupBoxWrapper {
 width: 550px;
 margin: 50px auto; 
 text-align: left;
}

.popupBoxContent {
 background-color: #FFF; 
 padding: 15px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#popup-Sub {
 -moz-border-radius: 0px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
   border-radius: 0px;
   height: 45px;
   background-color: #3232ff;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 15px;
   float: right;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   border-color: #1919ff;
   text-align: center;
   width: 80px;
   font-weight: bold;
}

.HeaderNote {
 color: #7E7E7E;
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 12px;
}

#Col {
 font-weight: bold;
}

table {
 border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: auto;
}

th, td {
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}

th {
 background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

#Oper {
 float: right;
 padding-right: 15px;
 cursor: default;
}

a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#NoteAv {
 top: 0; 
 left: 0; 
 position: fixed; 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 120%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
 display: none;
}

#Settings {
 top: 0; 
 left: 0; 
 position: fixed; 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 120%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
 display: none;
}

#FirstVisit {
 top: 0; 
 left: 0; 
 position: fixed; 
 width: 100%; 
 height: 120%;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
 display: none;
}


#MarkList {
 vertical-align: middle;
 position: fixed;
    display: inline;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 56px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #3A89D8;
    background-color: #eff5f9;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#MarkList > button {
 height: 36px;
 color: #39739d;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: #E1ECF4;
    border: 1px solid;
    display: inline;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #39739d;
}


.YelColBox {
 background-color: #F0F041;
}

.LastCol {
 background-color: #F0F041;
}

.GreColBox {
 background-color: #62ff62;
}

.BluColBox {
 background-color: #4199F0;
}

.PurColBox {
 background-color: #9941F0;
}

.RedColBox {
 background-color: #F04141;
}

.OraColBox {
 background-color: #F09941;
}

.ColorBox {   
 float: right;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

```html
<body onload="FirstVisit('Settings');">
  <div style="height: 30%;">
    <div>
      <a id="Oper" onClick="toggle_visibility('NoteAv');">Notes</a><a id="Oper" onClick="toggle_visibility('Settings');">Settings</a>
      <p id="header">Note Searcher</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <p id="form">
      <input onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length)" class="SearchInp" autocomplete="off" id="Bar" name="Input" type="text" placeholder="Removed JS for the fiddle.">
      <input class="SearchInp" type="submit" id="sea" onClick="SetOff ()" value="Search">
      <br>
      <input id="Highlight" type="radio" name="textOp" checked>Highlight
      <input id="Filter" type="radio" name="textOp">Filter
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="NoteHolder">
    <p class="NoteOp">
    Imagine if this filled up the whole text area. 
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id=Hid>

  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="note.js"></script>
  <footer id="MarkList">
  </footer>
</body>
```

A screenshot of the scrollbars:

[image: Screenshot showing scrollbars in Chrome]

Comment: what browser are you using? I see scrollbars in Chrome 49 on Windows 10, and Microsoft Edge, and Firefox 45. You might need to hit the Full page button.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you then.

Comment: Never mind. But how do I have it so it only shows the bars when there is an overflow? It is working I didn't see the bar.

Comment: Set a height. Your question was how to show scrollbars without seeing a height. There's no way for the browser to know when to show a scrollbar automatically without a height (or width) after which it should add the scrollbar...

Comment: One of the great things about web development is that it's really easy to use the developer tools of your browser to change CSS properties on the fly. I really encourage you to learn how to use them.